# Non-exhaustive pattern matches only because I left off `otherwise =`?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ghc, non-exhaustive-patterns

I wrote a simple program in Haskell that plays [the guessing game described in The Rust Programming Language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html):

> Here’s how it works: the program will generate a random integer between 1 and 100. It will then prompt the player to enter a guess. After entering a guess, it will indicate whether the guess is too low or too high. If the guess is correct, the game will print congratulations and exit.

Here is what I wrote:

```hs
import Control.Monad (when)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

-- | Check if the guess is correct, otherwise provide a hint
respond :: Int -> Int -> String
respond correct guess
  | guess > correct = "Smaller than " ++ show guess
  | guess < correct = "Larger than " ++ show guess
  | guess == correct = "Correct! " ++ show correct

-- | Main game loop; prompt for input and repeat until guessed correctly
play :: Int -> IO ()
play x = do
  putStr "Guess: "
  guess <- read <$> getLine
  putStrLn $ respond x guess
  when (guess /= x) $ play x

-- | Start the game with a random number between 1 and 100
main :: IO ()
main = play =<< randomRIO (1, 100)
```

The code works, but GHC gives me a warning that `"Pattern match(es) are non exhaustive. In an equation for 'respond': Patterns not matched:  _ _"`

I take those two underscores to represent the two `Ints` I have as arguments to the `respond` function. What I don't understand is which case I haven't covered. Those aren't `Maybe Int`s or anything special — the function *requires* two valid `Ints`, so I only need to deal with integers — and I don't think there is any number that cannot be deemed greater than, less than, or equal to another?

Is this just GHC assuming I have not covered all cases because I didn't add a final `otherwise =` guard? Even though it logically covers all cases.

---

Also, if you have any tips on how to write more idiomatic Haskell, I'd appreciate them. I'm still learning the basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHC simply doesn't know that one of `a > b`, `a < b`, or `a == b` must evaluate to `True`. (Indeed, it is possible to write an `Ord` instance that violates this assumption -- though most programmers would not consider doing so, and certainly the one for `Int` will behave nicely in this regard.)

You can make it patently obvious to GHC that you've covered all the cases by using a complete pattern match instead, e.g.

```
respond correct guess = case compare guess correct of
    GT -> ...
    LT -> ...
    EQ -> ...
```

GHC also has a special case in its exhaustiveness checker for the guards `otherwise` and `True`, so you may add (or replace) one of the guards with this as an alternative solution.

```
respond correct guess
    | guess > correct = ...
    | guess < correct = ...
    | otherwise = ...
```

Comment: I'd add that there _are_ `Ord` instances which are commonly used and for which this assumption doesn't hold: `Float` and `Double` (because of `NaN`).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does only a static semantic analysis. This is unable to see that the three cases cover all possible inputs because the meaning of the operators are determined at run-time.

Your code is provably correct. If you want to avoid the warning from GHC, you can change the final condition to `otherwise`.